# JQuery selector logic fails if id has '.' in the value. Any solution?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using Spring Forms for my web application. For nested properties, the form tag generates the input elements having id / name in form of .

For example, Person is the command class and Address is contained into its address field then the city element would be,

```
<input type="text" id="address**.**city" name="address**.**city" />
```

now, the problem is whenever I try to get its value using jQuery,

```
$("#address.city").val();
```

jQuery fails to select any appropriate element !

Please let me know any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a solution, but it seems various pieces of text are missing from your question. Perhaps worth it to edit those back in, to make it easier for folks who want to help out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#address\\.city").val();
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

> Note: if you wish to use any of the meta-characters described above as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes (`\`). For example:

```
#foo\\:bar
#foo\\[bar\\]
#foo\\.bar
```

Comment: 'ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")' - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 6):

```
$('[id="address.city"]')
```

will also work